# Django: How to filter patients from one department?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm using django v1.8.

I extended the existing User model.

`models.py`

```
class Institution(models.Model):
    user =  models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Demographic(models.Model):
    patient_id = models.IntegerField(unique= True ,primary_key=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.patient_id)
```

I have two users `doctor` and `nurse` that belong to the same department and I want both of them to have access to the same patients.

In a template I use a search engine to search patient.

In `views.py` I have this filter:

```
patient = Demographic.objects.filter(patient_id__icontains=id)
```

but the 2 users can search only between patients from their departments.

How can I achieve this in filter? What parameter should I include?

Comment: `__icontains`?! On a pk? an int! Are you worried about uppercase numbers?

Comment: You should probably make `Department` a model as well. And there should be explicit relations between user and department and `Demographic` (is that a patient?) and `Department`.

Comment: "I have two users doctor and nurse" -- so, you have exactly 2 users only? Or do you mean two types of users?

Comment: @C14L I may have one, two or more users from the same department and all these should have access to that patients.

Comment: @C14L `__icontains` is just for testing purposes. I will change it later.

Comment: What do you mean? `__icontains` only makes sense for text types.

Comment: @HåkenLid Yes, patient id is text. Right now I'm searching all ids that contain a character.

Comment: If patient_id is text then you should update your question to show the real code you're using. It isn't clear what problem you're actually trying to solve (to me)

Comment: I'm confused. How do you put text into a `IntegerField`?

Comment: @HåkenLid Sorry, patient_id contains only numbers in my country, that's why.

Comment: How do you know which department does a given patient belong? It's not clear to me from the models you've shown.

Comment: @bakkal A user belongs to a department when he inserts a patient as author then this patient belongs to that department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A user belongs to a department when he inserts a patient as author then this patient belongs to that department.

So let's get the `department` of a given `user` first:

```
user = request.user # the doctor, the nurse etc
department = Institution.objects.get(user=user).department
```

Now you want all patients (`Demographic` instances) where `author.institution.department = department`

```
patients = Demographic.objects.filter(author__institution__department=department)
```

Comment: Great, that's it! Thank you very much! Please include in `Demographic` filter `patient_id=id` because I'm searching for a specific `id` and I want both constraints to be satisfied.

Comment: On a side note: `.filter(user=user).first()` can be replaced with `.get(user=user)`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Hmm yeah I just saw it's a `OneToOneField` which works for `.get()`, I thought it was a relationship with multiplicity (where `.get()` would raise an exception if more than 1 match is found) Updating!

Answer (score 1):

I assume `author` is a kind of caretaker attached to the patient. Then you can do a `filter` on the user's department:

```
department = Institution.objects.get(user=request.user).department
demographic = Demographic.objects.filter(patient_id=id).filter(author__institution__department=department)
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct regarding the `author`. Using this code I get `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'department'` for the second line.